# python first web application - where

Tags: python

I am rookie in python - have experience in PHP

my service provider (Bluehost) say that python 2.6 is available, however I am not able to run any script (basic hello word) on it - probably because I try do it PHP way. create a script.php file and place the link to it in browser...  :)

Where I can find explanation for dummy like me what I should do with file script.py (hello world inside) in order to be executed and displayed in browser, I am guessing that compilation could be required

thank you

Bensiu

Comment: What web framework are you using? Do you have a link to the tutorial you are following and could you post that in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Apache, this [simple tutorial](http://narnia.cs.ttu.edu/drupal/node/43) will show you how to configure it and run a python "hello world" script (in the simplest, old-fashioned way: as a CGI script).

This system-administration/configuration part will of course be different with other web servers, or other and better way of running Python web app (WSGI in particular), but then, you're not telling us what server or approach (CGI vs WSGI vs others yet) you want to use, so, this is probably the best we can suggest!-)